# Removing a URL or any recurring phrase from all rows of a data frame in R

Tags: r

I have the following data frame named `bbchealth`:

```
head(bbchealth)
# A tibble: 6 x 1
  Tweets                                                    
  <chr>                                                     
1 Breast cancer risk test devised http://bbc.in/1CimpJF     
2 GP workload harming care - BMA poll http://bbc.in/1ChTBRv 
3 Short people's 'heart risk greater' http://bbc.in/1ChTANp 
4 New approach against HIV 'promising' http://bbc.in/1E6jAjt
5 Coalition 'undermined NHS' - doctors http://bbc.in/1CnLwK7
6 Review of case against NHS manager http://bbc.in/1Ffj6ci
```

As you can see, each row, which contains a single tweet, has a URL at the end. I would like to remove only this URL while leaving the rest of the data frame unaffected.

If I try to use something like `rm_url`, I get the following:

```
[1] "c(\"Breast cancer risk test devised \"GP workload harming care - BMA poll \"Short people's 'heart risk greater' \"New approach against HIV 'promising' \"Coalition 'undermined NHS' - doctors \"Review of case against NHS manager \"\\\"VIDEO: 'All day is empty, what am I going to do?' \"VIDEO: 'Overhaul needed' for end-of-life care \"Care for dying 'needs overhaul' \"VIDEO: NHS: Labour and Tory key policies \"Have GP services got worse? \"A&amp;E waiting hits new worst level \"Parties row over GP opening hours \"Why strenuous runs may not be so bad after all \"VIDEO: Health surcharge for non-EU patients \"VIDEO: Skin cancer spike 'from 60s holidays' \"\.........
```

That is, a single vector(?) consisting of a string of the tweets with the URLs removed.

The code I used was `rm_url(bbchealth, replacement = "")`.

If I use `gsub("http.*","",bbchealth)`, I get the following output:

```
[1] "c(\"Breast cancer risk test devised "
```

However, this is not what I want. I want to retain the columnar structure. That is,

```
# A tibble: 6 x 1
  Tweets                                                    
  <chr>                                                     
1 Breast cancer risk test devised  
2 GP workload harming care - BMA poll 
3 Short people's 'heart risk greater'  
4 New approach against HIV 'promising' 
5 Coalition 'undermined NHS' - doctors 
6 Review of case against NHS manager
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, with `stringi` package

```
dt <- data.frame(
  Tweets = c(
    "Breast cancer risk test devised http://bbc.in/1CimpJF ",
    "GP workload harming care - BMA poll http://bbc.in/1ChTBRv",
    "Short people's 'heart risk greater' http://bbc.in/1ChTANp "
  )
)

library(stringi)

dt$Tweets2 <- stringi::stri_replace_all_regex(dt$Tweets, "\\shttp://.*$", "")
```

Comment: This partially solves my problem. However, the output of the suggested code is a vector of strings:
    `[1] "Breast cancer risk test devised"     "GP workload harming care - BMA poll"   "Short people's 'heart risk greater'"`
I can of course convert this into a data frame again. However, is there any function that will take each row of the original data frame, remove the URL, and then leave behind a similar data frame sans the URLs?

Comment: Edited my solution. You can create new columns in a data frame, or even replace the Tweet column. I'd suggest reading some online tutorials about using data frames eg https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/r_data_frames.htm